# Неправильная фраза при ошибке в проверке в очереди проверок

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, очередь-проверок

Неправильная фраза при ошибке в проверке в очереди проверок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что-то не очень понятна враза:

> нужно **удалять** и **рекомендовать на удаление**

Мне кажется надо оставить только:

> нужно **удалять**

Answer (score 4):

Предложил другой [перевод](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/6747):

> В этом сообщении есть серьёзные недостатки, которые вряд ли можно исправить путём редактирования. Подобными недостатками могут быть оскорбления, спам, текст без смысла или не по теме. Подобные сообщения бесполезны, а порой даже вредны. Если при проверке вам попадаются такие, их нужно **удалять** или **рекомендовать их удаление**.

Заменил

> ...их нужно **удалять** и **рекомендовать на удаление**

На

> ...их нужно **удалять** или **рекомендовать их удаление**.

Comment: Утвердил. Будет в новых сборках. Текущая 2023.10.3.43658